# Why does the M function List.Transform place double quotes around strings with embedded commas?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

I have a native Oracle query running in an Excel workbook, and I'm passing the user-supplied values from a table into the queries WHERE clause.

I wrote a quick function in M that I think adds single quotes to a string that's passed in

```
(x) =>
let
    string_format = "'" & x & "'"

in
    string_format
```

I apply this function to a column and then transform the column to a list but any strings with embedded commas are surrounded by double quotes

```
text_tbl3 = Table.TransformColumns(text_tbl2,{{"Org_Names", string_format}})
text_ls = Table.ToList(text_tbl3)
```

[image: Output]

It's difficult to see, but TD,AMERITRADE is surrounded by double and single quotes like this : "'TD, AMERITRADE'".  I want it to read 'TD,AMERITRADE' , so it has the same formatting as the other cells, but I cannot figure out what causes the additional double quotes.

Comment: The comma is a common list delimiter. In order to ensure that the text is not split into two values at the comma, it is enclosed with the double quotes.

Comment: Thanks @teylyn.  I want the double quotes removed, because those values will be passed into a WHERE statement that doesn't allow double-quotes.  Would I have to write another function to remove the double quotes, or is there another way to get around the issue?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this behavior. Not getting any double quotes.

Comment: @AlexisOlson, thanks for your input.  Would you happen to know how to simply take the column and make it a comma-separated list.  I have as the table
```
Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="tbl_Org_Names"]},
```

I'm new to M code, so not sure what would give me the list.

Answer (score 1):

## Quoting text

> quick function in M that I think adds single quotes to a string that's passed in

Your function is correct. [`&` is the text concatenation operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/m-spec-operators#structure-combination).

[image: screenshot of quote_text results]

Because you're using a single expression, you could simplify it by removing the inner `let..in` expression. (If you don't open the `advanced editor` you won't see the outer `let..in` expression).

```
quote_text = (string as text) => "'" & string & "'"
```

## Note: Your screenshot has extra quotes

Your inputs were:

```
CHASE
CITI
"TD, AMERITRADE"
```

Which is why you end up with:

```
'CHASE'
'CITI'
'"TD, AMERITRADE"'
```

Your cell probably has quotes on `"TD, AMERITRADE"` but not on the others.

## Getting a comma separated list as a single string

`Text.Combine(list, separator=", ")` will create a string like a CSV file.

[image]

```
let
    list_names = table3[Company],
    // equivalent to: list_names = {"CHASE", "CITI", "TD, AMERITRADE"},

    without_quotes = Text.Combine(list_names, ", "),

    list_quoted = List.Transform(
        list_names,
        quote_text
    ),

    with_quotes = Text.Combine(list_quoted, ", "),

    results = [
        list_names = list_names,
        list_quoted = list_quoted,
        string_without_quotes = without_quotes,
        string_with_quotes = with_quotes,
        without_equal_to = "string = ""CHASE, CITI, TD, AMERITRADE""",
        with_equal_to = "string = ""'CHASE', 'CITI', 'TD, AMERITRADE'"""
    ]
in
    results
```

## How do we use that string in a native query?

My query uses `SQL` but the method is the same for Oracle.

`raw_sql_query` is your raw query. It uses the parameter `@Company`

`sql_parameters` is a `Record` type that declares all parameters you are using. Here we use your string with the `qoute_text` function.

`Value.NativeQuery` inserts the parameters for you.

```
let
    company = "TD, AMERITRADE",

    raw_sql_query = "
        select * from Table
            where Company = @Company
    ",

    sql_parameters = [
        Company = quote_text( company )
    ],

    source = Sql.Database(
        "localhost",
        "Adventure Works"
    ),

    results = Value.NativeQuery(
        source, 
        raw_sql_query,
        sql_parameters
    )
in
    results
```

## How do we test whether the string function is quoting correctly?

First create a new blank query. We call `quote_text()` to verify the output.

I used a `Record` named `results` so you can label and view every value on a single screen.

`manual_quote` uses the string concatenation operator to quote strings

`quote_string( sample_string )` inserts variables into a text template. Both return the exact same string.

`Text.Format` becomes cleaner the more complicated your template becomes. This function is simple enough it's not necessary.

## Your original function

This is what your function in the advanced editor looks like:

```
let
    quote_text = (x) => 
        let
            string_format = "'" & x & "'"
        in
            string_format
in
    quote_text
```

## You may remove the inner let

```
let
    quote_text_simple = (string as text) =>
        "'" & string & "'"
in
    quote_text_simple
```

## How you can use optional arguments and string **Templates**

```
let
    // a custom function to Surround a string with single quotes.    
    // A optional second argument lets you specify a different character
    quote_string = (input_string as text, optional character as text) =>
        let 
            character = if character = null then "'" else character,
            template = "#[quote]#[string]#[quote]",
            quoted_string = Text.Format(
                template,
                [
                    quote = character,
                    string = input_string
                ]
            )
        in
            quoted_string

in
    quote_string
```